# jQuery if found in string

Tags: jquery, if-statement

How can I have jQuery check to see if the content of a variable contains a specific word and have it execute an alert if matched?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking to check a javascript *variable* and not some element on the page, jQuery isn't going to really make it any easier/different than using plain javascript.

The other answers mentioned here using regex will work, but you might want to look at the [String object reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) or the [RegExp object reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) at w3schools, if you want to understand it better.

Answer (score 48):

```
if( str.indexOf( "your word" ) !== -1 )
```

or

```
if( str.search( /your regex/ig ) )
```

or

```
if( str.match( /your regex/ig ).length > 0 )
```

As it shows, you do not need jQuery to solve this problem.

But, hell, why not use [jQuery selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains) if you want:

```
$('#someId:contains(text)')
```

Comment: +1 It should be noted, for the askers understanding, that these solutions are plain javascript, and this problem doesn't need/use jquery.

Comment: The indexOf-solution should be the most efficient one.

Comment: @Jan: it probably would, especially if one is only looking for a known string. but the regex is better in more cases due to its flexibility

Comment: AFAIK, Internet Explorer (6, at least) doesn't have `indexOf`

Comment: Looks like IE6+ support String.indexOf, IE < 9 don't support Array.indexOf http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53xtt423%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: I'm surprised that jQuery contains selector doesn't let you select a variable local to the function or script.

Answer (score 0):

One word: Regular expressions.

Whoops, that were 2 words ;)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions

Regex:

```
/.(mystring\swhich\sshould\smatch)./
```

Comment: It should be noted, for the askers understanding, that this solution is plain javascript, and this problem doesn't need/use jquery.

Answer (score -1):

For an element, use String functions on its name or whatever other applicable attribute value:

```
if(jQuery("elementName").attr("attributeName").contains(...))
  callSomeJSFunction();
```

, or Regular Expressions. If it's something simple, string manipulation should be sufficient as other people have mentioned. Another great resource are the [jQuery API pages](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) or countless other tutorials found through a Google search. Google's groups are often another useful resource.